# Replicate() using for loop in R

Tags: r

I'd like to create a large number of samples in R and store them in a variable. I did some research and probably the best way is to use replicate()

```
record <- replicate(5000, sample(c(0,1), size = 60, replace = T,prob=c(0.9,0.1)))
```

My question is how would I do it using for loop? I can create 5000 samples using for loop but how do I store them?

```
x <- 'something here' #I want to store them in x

for (i in 1:5000)
    {record <- sample(c(0,1), size = 60, replace = T,prob=c(0.9,0.1))
    'x += record'}
```

Edit:
The line X+= record is confusing. Here is my best shot at explaining that, in python I'd create a list and inside that list there'd be 5000 other lists each containing a different sample

Comment: Pre-allocate `record` and use indices in order to populate it

Comment: You mean like X <- 1:5000 and in my for loop I'd have X[i]?

Comment: `m <- matrix(0, 60, 500) ; for(i in seq_len(ncol(m))) m[, i] <- sample(c(0,1), size = 60, replace = T,prob=c(0.9,0.1))`. Though you don't really need a loop here.

Comment: I think what he wants is to add those sampled values to a vector `x`. But since he does not participate here I'm out.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for

Comment: It's hard to explain something in R when I'm just a noob. Here is my best shot, in python I'd create a list and inside that list there'd be 5000 other lists each containing a different sample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no point in using a `for` loop; nor is there a need for `replicate`.

You can draw `5000 * 60` independent samples directly using

```
smpl <- sample(c(0, 1), size = 60 * 5000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.9, 0.1))
```

If you want to store `smpl` in a matrix, you can recast the vector as a `matrix`, e.g.

```
mat <- matrix(smpl, ncol = 5000)
```

This will give you a `60 x 5000` matrix, where every column contains `5000` random samples drawn from a distribution with `p(0) = 0.9` and `p(1) = 0.1`.

This will be faster than using a `for` loop or `replicate`.

Comment: Thank you I know it's not the best idea to use for loop, but I wanted to know how it's done using for loop

Comment: @OmOWalker Using `replicate` is also not necessary (and it's definitely not *"the best way"*). Repeating the process of drawing `60` independent samples `5000` times is the same (but slower) as drawing `60*5000` independent samples in one go. Also, there are many cases where using a `for` loop makes sense in R programming; this is not one of them.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but to be fair we do not have any context. Sometimes efficiency is not at stake and having an easy to understand code is of higher importance.

Comment: @nate.edwinton I'm sorry but this is really not a matter of context. Are you telling me that a `for` loop spanning multiple lines makes the code easier to understand than a single `sample` call? Efficiency is almost *always* a critical issue in coding sampling problems. Either way, this is a moot discussion, and as long as OP has found what he/she was looking for it's all good.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
x <- list() # or x <- c() or x <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:5000){
    record <- sample(c(0,1), size = 60, replace = T,prob=c(0.9,0.1))
    x[[i]] <- record # or x <- c(x, record) or x <- rbind(x, record)
}
```

But yeah, not using a loop is probably better here, as indicated above.

Comment: This works nice, but if I use table(result) it gives me 1 table, here if I use table(X) it'd give me 5000 tables no?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you want to have a data frame of size `5000*60` then just turn your `list` `x` into a `data.frame`: `df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(x), nrow=5000, byrow=T))`.

Comment: if you insist on doing it 5000 independent samples do:
`replicate(5000,{sample(0:1,60,prob=c(0.01,0.99),replace=T)})`
this will return an array of size 5000 x 60.
If you want to have a list the "R-way" would be to use lapply:
`x <- lapply(1:5000,function(x){sample(0:1,100,prob=c(0.01,0.99),replace=T)})`